# With Quartz.Net, how do i find out how many times a trigger has fired

Tags: quartz-scheduler, quartz.net

I'm using ADOJobStore with my scheduler and in the DB I can see columns that indicate how many times my trigger has fired.  Is there someway to retrieve that data programmatically?  I can't seem to find it as a property on the Trigger.

```
var triggers = _scheduler.GetTriggersOfJob(jobDetails.Key);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can get this information if the trigger supports it. Following triggers have the **TimesTriggered** property:

- IDailyTimeIntervalTrigger
- ICalendarIntervalTrigger
- ISimpleTrigger

Which can also be inverted to: ICronTrigger does not support this so ITrigger interface does not have the information.

So you need to cast the trigger to some of the above types to get the information.